# Roblox game script to detect "sole survivor" winner

Tags: lua, roblox

I am working on a 6 player rounds-based Roblox game with each round ending if either time runs out OR if every player except for one survivor remains. After each round players (and those killed during the round) are teleported back to a lobby, followed by a brief intermission, and then teleported bak into a map to start a new round (there are lots of different maps chosen randomly). My strategy for this game was to create a large region surrounding all the maps and during the rounds as the timer is counting down, continually detect the # players in the region. When that number gets to 1 the round would end and a winner would be declared. There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. I had to create a huge region to encompass all the different maps and as I add more maps the region will have to get bigger and bigger. Is detecting # players in such a large region when at most 6 players will be in only one map at a time?
2. My player detection script isn't working. It detects one player but when there are 2 players it still returns "1" as # of players. To trouble shoot this problem I created a simple game that detects when a player is in a region (gray baseplate) and when they leave the region (red baseplate). When I run the game - https://www.roblox.com/games/6060804433/Rounds - publicly with 2 players in the game it only returns 1 player in the game (which I display in an upper left GUI).  My code is below - I think the problem is with how the table / dictionary playersFound works.

CODE:

```
regionPart = game.Workspace.RegionFromThisPart -- I created a transparent cube to define the region
pos1, pos2 = (regionPart.Position - (regionPart.Size/2)),(regionPart.Position + (regionPart.Size/2))
region = Region3.new(pos1,pos2)
Status = game.ReplicatedStorage.Status

wait(5)

while wait(1) do

    partsInRegion = workspace:FindPartsInRegion3(region, game.Workspace.Baseplate,1000) 
    playersFound = {} -- table of players found

    for i, part in pairs (partsInRegion) do
        if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
            playersFound["playerinregion"] = part.Parent -- add players character to table
            print (i, part) -- 0
        end 
    end

    function Length(playersFound)
        local counter = 0 
        for _, v in pairs(playersFound) do
            counter =counter + 1
        end
        return counter
    end

    Status.Value = Length(playersFound) .." players in region"

end
```

---

Bonus question: The GUI I created to show the number of players in the region shows on my screen but not the other player's scree (it says "label" on their screen).

I have spent an incredible amount of time spinning my wheels and would GREATLY appreciate help solving this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right that your issue stems from how you're putting players into your `playersFound` table. Because you are using the same key in the table every time, you are overwriting the old player with any new one you find.
Instead, try using a unique key to hold onto the players. This could be `i` or better yet, the player's name. And since you are just looping over the table again, why not just keep a counter of how many players there are.

```
local regionPart = game.Workspace.RegionFromThisPart -- I created a transparent cube to define the region
local pos1 = (regionPart.Position - (regionPart.Size/2))
local pos2 = (regionPart.Position + (regionPart.Size/2))
local region = Region3.new(pos1,pos2)
local Status = game.ReplicatedStorage.Status
local BasePlate = game.Workspace.Baseplate
local time = 30 -- seconds

wait(5)

while wait(1) do
    
    -- count how many players are left
    local playersFound = {}
    local totalPlayersFound = 0
    local partsInRegion = workspace:FindPartsInRegion3(region, baseplate, 1000)
    for i, part in pairs(partsInRegion) do
        if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
            -- keep track of all the players still alive
            -- since a player's character is made of many parts, each player will show up multiple times,
            -- so only hold onto each player once
            local character = part.Parent
            if (playersFound[character.Name] == nil) then
                playersFound[character.Name] = character
                print ("Found Player : ", character.Name)
                totalPlayersFound = totalPlayersFound + 1
            end
        end 
    end

    -- EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS --
    -- update the UI based on the game state
    if time == 0 then
        Status.Value = "Round over!"
        break
    elseif totalPlayersFound == 1 then
        -- since we know that there's only one entry in the playersFound table,
        -- grab it using the next() function
        local playerName, character = next(playersFound)
        StatusValue = "Winner : " .. playerName
        wait(5)
        break
    --elseif totalPlayersFound  == 0 then
        -- make sure to check in case no players are left
    else
        Status.Value = tostring(totalPlayersFound) .. " players in round"
        time = time - 1
        -- DEBUG :
        -- print("There are " .. tostring(totalPlayersFound) .. " players in the round")
        -- for playerName, character in pairs(playersFound) do
        --     print(" - " .. playerName .. " is still in the game")
        -- end
    end
end
```

As for your bonus question, you should ask a follow up question and post the code that shows how you're creating the label and updating it.

Comment: Also, if you don't need a dictionary for specialized indexing, you could simply use an array to store the player characters : ```table.insert(playersFound, part.Parent)``` and then later get the count with the length operator ```Status.Value = tostring(#playersFound) .. " players in region "```

Comment: Kylaaa, Thanks a lot! This worked. I have a follow up question: Later in my script (outside the loop that you wrote up) I would like to display the winning players name. But when I tried to do that by referencing playersFound[part.Parent.Name] it doesn't seem to recognize it (the word 'part' is underlined in the script. And I get "nil" returned when I print it. any suggestions? thanks again!

Comment: @Kevind, the value that is saved into each key _is_ the player's name. You can iterate over all of the keys using the `pairs` keyword even though you know that there's only one entry in the dictionary : ```for playerName, playerCharacter in pairs(playersFound) do print("The winning Player is : ", playerName") end```.

Comment: A better solution would just be to use an array, because then you can grab the last player using ```print("The winning Player is : ", playersFound[1].Name)```

Comment: Struggling a bit to figure out how to implement that. Here is the code where I decide to end the round because the time ran out or if there is a sole player remaining who becomes the winner: if time == 0 then
   Status.Value = "Round over!"
   break
  elseif Length(playersFound)== 1 then  
    StatusValue = "Winner" 
   wait(5)
   break
  else
   Status.Value = Length(playersFound) .." players in round)"
   time = time - 1
  end

Comment: I inserted your code in the place where I have StatusValue = "Winner" (this is what I use to power the GUI). But when I inserted your code and changed it from print to StatusValue =  it got underlined and didn't seem to work.

Comment: If I switch to the array, and use the table.insert script you shared, would it look like this? for i, part in pairs (partsInRegion) do
   if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
    table.insert(playersFound, part.Parent) 
   end

Comment: I've updated my code sample based on the conversation to highlight how to use the array approach.

Comment: When i replaced my code with your array approach it doesn't work (and says there are 18 players in the game when there should be only one). Things are working much better with the table approach but I can't figure out what the actual structure of the table is and how to access it. When I run the command print playersFound I get  ▼  {
                    ["coopersfather"] = coopersfather. (coopersfather is the player name). So I thought that Status.Value = playersFound[2] would work but it returns nil. How do I extract that name from the table so I can display it? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Kevind, sorry for the bad example. I forgot that a player's character has multiple body parts and each body part would show up in the count.  As for the structure of a table, think of it like this : a table is just a container for keys and values. Arrays automatically assign numbers for the keys. ```local t = {}; table.insert(t, "a"); table.insert(t, "b")``` In this array, `t[1] = "a"` and `t[2] = "b"` and you can loop over all of them using `for i, v in ipairs(t) do print( i,  t[i], v)`  In my example, you'll notice that `t[i]` is the same thing as `v`

Comment: In a dictionary, you can manually assign the values to specific keys. ```local t = {};  t["a"] = 1; t["b"] = 2``` In this table,  you can access the keys directly with `print( t.a )` or `print( t["a"])` or, you can iterate over all of the keys using `for k, v in pairs(t) do print( k, t[k], v)`. Dictionaries are useful for when you are making intentional choices about how you store your data because you can use a known value to jump directly to the stored data.

Comment: In your case, you're interested in the player's name, which it is currently being used as a key for looking up the player's character. But since you don't know what that key is, you can use the `pairs()` function to loop over the one entry like this :  `for playerName, character in pairs(foundPlayers) do print(playerName) end`  OR, you can use the `next()` function to grab the key-value pair like this : `local playerName, character = next(foundPlayers)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining Sorry this is taking so long. Here is what I have found in trying to retrieve the name of the winner. I am able to print (playersFound[part.Parent.Name]) and get the players name. But when I try to display the name as follows Status.Value = playersFound[part.Parent.Name] I get an error saying " invalid argument #3 (string expected, got Instance)." So it seems like maybe my issue is figuring out how to turn this "instance" into a string (I looked of instances and got confused)...

Comment: The instance is the character. `part.Parent.Name` is the string you're looking for. You could also do `playersFound[part.Parent.Name].Name` you get the player's name